# Percent of records within a group in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Please refer to the image below. Currently I am seeing the sum of yes/no responses for each age group. I would like to see percent of yes/no responses within each age group. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Add quick table calculation `Percent of total`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for Table Calculations:
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_create.html

In this case, click the measure `SUM(Number of Records)` and choose to add a % of Total quick table calculation from the menu.

Comment: You may have to edit the table calc to specify the scope of the calculation — I.e. whether to calculate the percentage within each age group or for the whole data set